# vue boolean property not working

Tags: vue.js

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#one-example',
  props: {
    maximize: Boolean,
  },
});

<div id="one-example" maximize>
  <p v-if="maximize">Hello vue!</p>
  {{maximize}}
</div>
```

What am I missing here? `{{maximize}}` is false here, shouldnt it be true since its initialized here? `<div id="one-example" maximize>`

https://jsfiddle.net/8ucdt58p/

Comment: according to this [answer here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6440#issuecomment-324591537) by  a Vue core member: *"Props are for passing data form a parent component to a child component."*

Comment: How would you initialize a component with a specific behavior based in a property then? using the data?

Comment: I think the confusion here is around what a component is. Components in Vue absolutely accept properties. Root Vue components (those you create using `new Vue()`) do not.

Comment: How could I make a root vue componet configurable then? should I wrap it in a parent component like <div id="app">

Comment: Typically, you initialize using data as suggested in the first answer below.

Comment: Or you may be looking for something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/8ucdt58p/2/).

Comment: @lapinkoira did you see the second option on my answer? It looks like what you're looking for.. isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve with this.
But I think that you should put maximize in data.

```
<div id="one-example" >  
  <p v-if="maximize">Hello vue!</p>
  {{maximize}}
</div>


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#one-example',
  data: function(){
   return{
    maximize:true
   }
  }
});
```

Otherwise via component & props:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app">
      <one-example :maximize="false"></one-example>
    </div>

    <script>
        Vue.component('one-example', {
         props: ['maximize'],
         template: '<div  >  <p v-if="maximize">Hello vue!</p>  {{maximize}} </div>'
       });

       var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app'
       });

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In case you don't need a true/false state for maximize but a set-to-something/unset ......
(As stated in the comments below) maximize can be set also like:

```
   <one-example maximize="anything"></one-example>
```

or not set or void

```
   <one-example ></one-example>
   <one-example maximize=""></one-example>
```

Comment: `:maximize` should be `maximize` since you're passing down a literal. Other than that, I think this is what the op is after.

Comment: Good point I edited the answer accordingly. But I think in the question is asking only for a boolean state, then binding maximize as boolean would fit better IMHO.